# counting row or records using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been trying to count number of rows using hibernate but I keep getting "0" records. Here is my code

```
public static Integer getLastDrugId(){
    Integer result = 0;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "SELECT count(*) FROM Drug";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        Integer e = (Integer) query.iterate().next();
        if (e != null) {
            result = 1;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Am i getting it wrong somewhere?

Comment: Have you checked if you are getting an Exception? You should probably add a logger and have it print the stacktrace in your catch block to not miss it.

Comment: i am somehow new to counting rows. but i got this error now after printing the stacktrace "java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer". but i didnt use Long anywhere in my code

Comment: Looks like your Query returns a Long so you have to recieve it as such. If you need the result as an Integer you can do the convertion manually by calling intValue() on the Long the query returns.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

```
Integer e = (Integer) query.iterate().next();
```

whith this:

```
Long e = (Long) query.iterate().next();
```

Comment: thanks! this works at first but now it keeps returning just a record and i have two records

Comment: how can a Count(*) return two records (in above query)? 
`SELECT count(*) FROM Drug;` Run this in database and see by yourself.

Comment: Im new to this so i really dont understand how it works fully. okay i want to return more than one record. i want to use the number of records as an id, like if i have one record, the next id should be "2"..

Comment: do i need to change my query?

Comment: i just ran "SELECT count(*) FROM Drug;" and i got "2"

Comment: i dont know if it is my jquery that has the problem now. " $("#drugid")[0].value = 'DRUG00'+ <%=lastDrugId + 1%>;"